# only get next instance in the entire document

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to simply target ONLY the first instance of an element in the document after a clicked element. This is what I came up with:

```
$('.class').click(function(){
    var x = $(this).nextAll('.anotherclass').first();
    //do something
});
```

but this will only be able to grab from the siblings of `.class` meaning that if there is no instance of `.anotherclass` as a sibling, it will not continue to go through the document.

I want it to simply grab the `.anotherclass` instance that I would fine if I went through the html line by line starting at the clicked `.class`

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 1):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rmwNS/

```
var x = $('.class, .anotherClass');
var y = x.slice( x.index( $(this) ), x.length).filter('.anotherClass').first();
```

the order of the nodes in the document is preserved in x, so slicing away everything before the clicked node gives you a starting point for finding the first occurrence of `.anotherClass`

Comment: This is a great solution, and deserves more upvotes. I was messing around with this one myself, and I learned a few things I didn't know about jQuery from this answer. Good stuff!

Answer (score 0):

select all, then filter down to only the one that is the index of current one + 1.

```
$(".anotherclass").eq( $(this).index(".anotherclass") + 1)
```

Comment: Will this continue along the DOM or only work if what he wants is the very next element?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what he means by continuing along the dom. That doesn't quite make sense in this context other than getting the next in the dom based on the clicked one.

Comment: he means that he wants the next element with class `.anotherclass` even if it is all the way at the end of the document, anywhere after his clicked element

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should do it in multiple steps

```
$('.class').click(function(){
  var x.length = 0; 
  x = $(this).siblings('.anotherclass').first(); //check siblings
  if (x.length < 1)
      //check here in another portion of code
});
```

I have never heard of interrupting the selection process in jquery. So I would try something like the above